# How to use Git Bash to create a zip file between commits ignoring deleted files

Tags: bitbucket, git-bash, git-gui

I use Bitbucket and I am looking to create a zip file between commits so that I can supply only the changed files to a client. I currently use:

```
git archive --output=changes.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only SHA1 SHA2)
```

Which works absolutely fine if all the files are there. However if there is a file that has been deleted between commits I get the error:

```
fatal: pathspec 'FILENAME' did not match any files
```

What is the best way of doing this, can you do it in Bitbucket, Git Gui or Git Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the option diff-filter with lowercase d excludes deleted files:

```
git archive --output=changes.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d SHA1 SHA2)
```